# Prevent overlapping TSRANGE

Tags: postgresql

I have the following PG (12) `reservations` table

```
id               uuid
reservable_id    uuid
reserved_between tsrange
```

How can I ensure there are no 2 reservations for the same `reservable_id` overlapping each other?

A "simple" UNIQUE INDEX on `reservable_id`,`reserved_between` works only (as expected) only with equal ranges.

Comment: [Range Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html), overlap operator `&&`. Use in trigger logic. "Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `btree_gist` extension so that you can create a GiST index on an `uuid`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Now you can create an exclusion constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE reservations ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   reservable_id WITH =,
   reserved_between WITH &&
);
```

`&&` is the “overlaps” operator for ranges.

Comment: Hi Laurentz, That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.